# Avoid <item type> node from creating in JSON to XML converter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml

We are trying to convert JSON to XML with following C# code:

```
Object httpConn = Dts.Connections["HTTP"].AcquireConnection(null);
            HttpClientConnection myConnection = new HttpClientConnection(httpConn);
            myConnection.ServerURL = string.Format(("http://xxxx.com/jjjj"),"userid","password");
            byte[] webdata = myConnection.DownloadData();

            String result_data = Convert.ToBase64String(webdata);
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDictionaryReader xr = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(webdata, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

            xr.Read();
            xd.LoadXml(xr.ReadOuterXml());
            xd.Save("\\Server\\ZZZZ\\Downloads\\Data.xml");
```

The sample json is:

```
[
{
        "id" : 21953,
        "mainReqIdentity" : "xxxx",
        "itemName" : "xxxx",
        "kanbanPhase" : "xxxx",
        "kanbanStatus" : "xxxx",
        "backlogItemType" : "xxxx",
        "identityDomain" : "xxxx",
        "fromDatetime" : "2016-08-05 17:52:34",
        "teams" : [],
        "releases" : [{
                "id" : 1229,
                "release_name" : "xxxx",
                "release_connection_type" : "xxxx"
            }
        ],
        "fpReleases" : [],
        "sources" : [{
                "sourceName" : "xxxx",
                "sourceRecordUrl" : "xxxx",
                "sourceRecordIdentity" : "xxxx"
            }
        ],
        "productNumbers" : [],
        "tags" : [],
        "productComponents" : [],
        "ranPlatforms" : [],
        "subReleases" : [],
        "requirementAreaId" : "xxxx",
        "requirementArea" : "xxxx",
        "toBeHandledAtxxxx" : "xxxx"
    }, {
        "id" : 22014,
        "mainReqIdentity" : "xxxx",
        "itemName" : "xxxx",
        "kanbanPhase" : "xxxx",
        "kanbanStatus" : "xxxx",
        "backlogItemType" : "xxxx",
        "identityDomain" : "xxxx",
        "fromDatetime" : "2016-08-05 17:52:34",
        "teams" : [],
        "releases" : [{
                "id" : "xxxx",
                "release_name" : "xxxx",
                "release_connection_type" : "xxxx"
            }
        ],
        "fpReleases" : [],
        "sources" : [{
                "sourceName" : "xxxx",
                "sourceRecordUrl" : "xxxx",
                "sourceRecordIdentity" : "xxxx"
            }
        ],
        "productNumbers" : [],
        "tags" : [],
        "productComponents" : [],
        "ranPlatforms" : [],
        "subReleases" : [],
        "requirementAreaId" : "xxxx",
        "requirementArea" : "xxxx",
        "f0Date" : "2015-10-01",
        "f1Date" : "2015-10-01",
        "f2Date" : "2016-02-01",
        "f4Date" : "2016-03-31",
        "fgDate" : "2016-04-29",
        "toBeHandledAtxxxx" : "xxxx"
    }
    ]
```

After the conversion the XML looks like:

```
    <root type="array">
    <id type="number">21286</id>
    <mainReqIdentity type="string">xxxxxx</mainReqIdentity>
    <itemName type="string">xxxxxx</itemName>
    <kanbanPhase type="string">xxxxxx</kanbanPhase>
    <kanbanStatus type="string">xxxxxx</kanbanStatus>
    <kanbanNote type="string">xxxxxx</kanbanNote>
    <backlogItemType type="string">xxxxxx</backlogItemType>
    <identityDomain type="string">xxxxxx</identityDomain>
    <fromDatetime type="string">2016-08-23 17:01:52</fromDatetime>
    <teams type="array">
      <item type="object">
        <team_name type="string">xxxxxx</team_name>
        <preliminary type="boolean">xxxxxx</preliminary>
      </item>
    </teams>
    <releases type="array">
      <item type="object">
        <id type="number">xxxxxx</id>
        <release_name type="string">xxxxxx</release_name>
        <release_connection_type type="string">xxxxxx</release_connection_type>
      </item>
    </releases>
    <fpReleases type="array">
    </fpReleases>
    <sources type="array">
      <item type="object">
        <sourceName type="string">xxxxxx</sourceName>
        <sourceRecordUrl type="string">xxxxxx</sourceRecordUrl>
      </item>
    </sources>
    <productNumbers type="array">
    </productNumbers>
    <tags type="array">
    </tags>
    <productComponents type="array">
    </productComponents>
    <ranPlatforms type="array">
    </ranPlatforms>
    <subReleases type="array">
    </subReleases>
    <requirementAreaId type="number">xxxxxx</requirementAreaId>
    <requirementArea type="string">xxxxxx</requirementArea>
    <itemContact type="string">xxxxxx</itemContact>
    <toBeHandledAtxxx type="string">xxxxxx</toBeHandledAtxxx>
  </item>
    <item type="object">
    <id type="number">xxxxxx</id>
    <mainReqIdentity type="string">xxxxxx</mainReqIdentity>
    <itemName type="string">xxxxxx</itemName>
    <kanbanPhase type="string">xxxxxx</kanbanPhase>
    <kanbanStatus type="string">xxxxxx</kanbanStatus>
    <kanbanNote type="string">xxxxxx</kanbanNote>
    <backlogItemType type="string">xxxxxx</backlogItemType>
    <identityDomain type="string">xxxxxx</identityDomain>
    <fromDatetime type="string">2016-08-23 17:01:52</fromDatetime>
    <teams type="array">
      <item type="object">
        <team_name type="string">xxxxxx</team_name>
        <preliminary type="boolean">xxxxxx</preliminary>
      </item>
    </teams>
    <releases type="array">
      <item type="object">
        <id type="number">xxxxxx</id>
        <release_name type="string">xxxxxx</release_name>
        <release_connection_type type="string">xxxxxx</release_connection_type>
      </item>
    </releases>
    <fpReleases type="array">
    </fpReleases>
    <sources type="array">
      <item type="object">
        <sourceName type="string">xxxxxx</sourceName>
        <sourceRecordUrl type="string">xxxxxx</sourceRecordUrl>
      </item>
    </sources>
    <productNumbers type="array">
    </productNumbers>
    <tags type="array">
    </tags>
    <productComponents type="array">
    </productComponents>
    <ranPlatforms type="array">
    </ranPlatforms>
    <subReleases type="array">
    </subReleases>
    <requirementAreaId type="number">xxxxxx</requirementAreaId>
    <requirementArea type="string">xxxxxx</requirementArea>
    <oaResultReference type="string">xxxxxx</oaResultReference>
    <itemContact type="string">xxxxxx</itemContact>
    <f0Date type="string">2014-10-17</f0Date>
    <f1Date type="string">2015-01-16</f1Date>
    <f2Date type="string">2015-02-13</f2Date>
    <f4Date type="string">2015-06-12</f4Date>
    <faDate type="string">2015-06-12</faDate>
    <fgDate type="string">2015-06-12</fgDate>
    <toBeHandledAtxxx type="string">xxxxxx</toBeHandledAtxxx>
  </item>
 </root>
```

If you observer before every node a ***item type*** is created. My question is how to avoid creating them from the C# class.

Comment: What do you want, you are reading it in as a `Dictionary<string,object>`? If you would make a hardcoded dto class that reads the JSON and use that one to serialize the output you wouldn't have this problem. But then you are bound to a (somewhat) fixed structure. The way you are serializing it now, it adds the type so it could potentially unserialize it back at a later time

Comment: Sorry i am new to c#, can you point me to a sample code?

Comment: The question in the end would be, how do you want it to be serialized. I can imagine you might want to simplify the xmlserialization a bit

Comment: You wrote, *If you observer before every node a **item type** is created.*  This is not correct.   A `type=` *attribute* is created for every element.  An `<item type="object">` node is created for each array item - but not for every node.  Which do you want to prevent or remove?

Answer (score 2):

The correspondence between XML and JSON used by `JsonReaderWriterFactory` is described in [Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx).  In particular:

- Since XML does not have the concept of an array primitive, a JSON array is mapped to two levels of XML where the inner element’s [local name] will be "item".
- An attribute `"type"` is added to each element.  As stated in the docs, *This attribute is used to preserve the JSON type (string, number, boolean, object, array or null) in the mapped XML.*

If this mapping does not meet your needs, you can customize the resulting XML using some appropriate API such as an [XSLT transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693190.aspx) modification before storing the XML.

For instance, [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693069.aspx), the API which superseded the `XmlDocument` API in .Net 3.5, allows for easy modification of XML in memory.  First, load your JSON into an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
XDocument xd;
using (var xr = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(webdata, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
{
    xd = XDocument.Load(xr);
}
```

Now, if you would like to "un-nest" the array items from their outer container element, you can do it as follows - except in the case of the root element.  If the [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) of the XML document corresponds to a JSON array its items cannot be bubbled out because doing so would violate the rule that each XML document must have [exactly one root element](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root).  That being said, the following should work:

```
foreach (var arrayElement in xd.Root.Descendants().Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("type") == "array").ToList())
{
    // Get all child nodes of the array container node.
    var nodes = arrayElement.Nodes().ToList();
    bool anyChildren = false;
    // Change names of child elements from <item> to the name of the container node, <releases> or whatever.
    foreach (var element in nodes.OfType<XElement>())
    {
        anyChildren = true;
        element.Name = arrayElement.Name;
    }
    if (anyChildren)
    {
        // Remove all its child nodes.
        nodes.Remove();
        // Add formerly child nodes right after the container node.
        arrayElement.AddAfterSelf(nodes);
        // Remove the container node itself.
        arrayElement.Remove();
    }
}
```

(This code may need to be customized further for nested JSON arrays.)

Next, if you wish to remove the `"type"` attributes, the following code can be used:

```
foreach (var element in xd.Descendants().Where(e => e.Attribute("type") != null))
    element.Attributes("type").Remove();
```

Finally, to save the document afterwards, do:

```
xd.Save("\\Server\\ZZZZ\\Downloads\\Data.xml");
```

The result of chaining these two transformation is:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <id>21953</id>
    <mainReqIdentity>xxxx</mainReqIdentity>
    <itemName>xxxx</itemName>
    <kanbanPhase>xxxx</kanbanPhase>
    <kanbanStatus>xxxx</kanbanStatus>
    <backlogItemType>xxxx</backlogItemType>
    <identityDomain>xxxx</identityDomain>
    <fromDatetime>2016-08-05 17:52:34</fromDatetime>
    <teams></teams>
    <releases>
      <id>1229</id>
      <release_name>xxxx</release_name>
      <release_connection_type>xxxx</release_connection_type>
    </releases>
    <fpReleases></fpReleases>
    <sources>
      <sourceName>xxxx</sourceName>
      <sourceRecordUrl>xxxx</sourceRecordUrl>
      <sourceRecordIdentity>xxxx</sourceRecordIdentity>
    </sources>
    <productNumbers></productNumbers>
    <tags></tags>
    <productComponents></productComponents>
    <ranPlatforms></ranPlatforms>
    <subReleases></subReleases>
    <requirementAreaId>xxxx</requirementAreaId>
    <requirementArea>xxxx</requirementArea>
    <toBeHandledAtxxxx>xxxx</toBeHandledAtxxxx>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>22014</id>
    <mainReqIdentity>xxxx</mainReqIdentity>
    <itemName>xxxx</itemName>
    <kanbanPhase>xxxx</kanbanPhase>
    <kanbanStatus>xxxx</kanbanStatus>
    <backlogItemType>xxxx</backlogItemType>
    <identityDomain>xxxx</identityDomain>
    <fromDatetime>2016-08-05 17:52:34</fromDatetime>
    <teams></teams>
    <releases>
      <id>xxxx</id>
      <release_name>xxxx</release_name>
      <release_connection_type>xxxx</release_connection_type>
    </releases>
    <fpReleases></fpReleases>
    <sources>
      <sourceName>xxxx</sourceName>
      <sourceRecordUrl>xxxx</sourceRecordUrl>
      <sourceRecordIdentity>xxxx</sourceRecordIdentity>
    </sources>
    <productNumbers></productNumbers>
    <tags></tags>
    <productComponents></productComponents>
    <ranPlatforms></ranPlatforms>
    <subReleases></subReleases>
    <requirementAreaId>xxxx</requirementAreaId>
    <requirementArea>xxxx</requirementArea>
    <f0Date>2015-10-01</f0Date>
    <f1Date>2015-10-01</f1Date>
    <f2Date>2016-02-01</f2Date>
    <f4Date>2016-03-31</f4Date>
    <fgDate>2016-04-29</fgDate>
    <toBeHandledAtxxxx>xxxx</toBeHandledAtxxxx>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Send promising, let me try, give me a day or two