# How to flatten XML created from converting JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml

After converting JSON to XML using:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json), new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()));
```

I get an output similar to:

```
<a type="object">
    <b type="array">
        <item type="object">
            ...
        </item>
        <item type="object">
            ...
        </item>
    </b>
</a>
```

Does anyone know a nice simple way of actually making the XML look like so:

```
<a type="object">
    <b type="object">
        ...
    </b>
    <b type="object">
        ...
    </b>
</a>
```

I need it in this format to match my XSLT transform template.

Many thanks,
Kai

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid <item type> node from creating in JSON to XML converter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213787/avoid-item-type-node-from-creating-in-json-to-xml-converter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Sinatr That's perfect, thank you!

Comment: Answer can be found at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213787/avoid-item-type-node-from-creating-in-json-to-xml-converter-in-c-sharp As per Sinatr's comment

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication117
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILE = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILE = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILE);

            XElement b = doc.Descendants("b").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> items = b.Descendants("item").Select(x =>
                new XElement("b", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("type", "object"),
                        x.Nodes()
                    })
                ).ToList();

            b.ReplaceWith(items);

            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILE);
        }
    }
}
```